# Activity Monitor in Mac not showing network usage

Tags: networking, macos

Have had Activity monitor open for the day in the background and have been tethered to my phone for the last couple of hours until I got a warning on my phone that I've used 1.3gb of data and my phone data is now maxed out.  The thing is that I havent used that much internet since I've been tethered.

Had a look in the Activity Monitor and can see that I've sent and receieved GBs of data, but nothing in the process list shows anything even close to the usage.  The highest out is 18mb and 156mb, and these are outlyers in the list.  The 156mb is for pgAdmin, which is from local traffic with my local database I've been working on.

Is there any other way (without starting from scratch, since I'm almost out of phone data) to see what used the 1.3gb of data?[image]

Comment: Noticed my network still going nuts when I was offline, which I managed to isolate to a Google Chrome tab.  This leads me to believe it was a webpage chewing up my data.  My current theory; that it wasn't showing since Chrome uses helper processes, which come and go, possibly in the case of an _iFrame_ being used by a rotating ad space (man I hate ads). This could explain why nothing has any large usage of data.   thoughts?

Comment: Hmm...my CPU has also quieten down too....interesting.

Comment: I'm also having "Activity Monitor (AM) in Mac not showing network usage".  I'm seeing it in action.  A network backup app is running, and AM shows data being sent and receieved at the bottom appropriately, but "nothing in the process list shows anything even close to the usage".  Some short-lived processes could be to blame.

Comment: @GuyPark did you figure out anything on this issue? i'm seeing the same and i can't figure out where my 1GB of hotspot data went

Comment: @bivo-kasaju , alas no.  After spending too much time on it, had a feeling I would have to go deep into the system core to figure it out, so decided on giving up and accepting it at that point as a loss and moved on.   If you do figure it out, please do let us know.  :)   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It was caused by the fact that only a user's own processes are shown by default.

To fix: click "View" and ensure "All processes" is enabled. Also ensure there are no other filters enabled.